# Guarantee of non-equality of pointers to standard functions?

Tags: c, language-lawyer, function-pointers, c-standard-library

Does the C language guarantee that pointers to differently-named standard functions must compare not-equal?

Per *6.5.9 Equality Operators*, ¶6,

> Two pointers compare equal if and only if both are null pointers, both are pointers to the same object (including a pointer to an object and a subobject at its beginning) or function, ...

I seem to recall seeing an interpretation claiming that aliases (multiple identifiers for the "same function") are permissible for standard functions, the canonical candidates for such treatment being `getc==fgetc` and `putc==fputc`; however, I don't know where I might have seen it, and I'm skeptical of the concept.

Is there any official interpretation or well-accepted argument for or against this possibility?

Comment: I suspect `strtoll(),strtoimax()` could then be as `getc()/fgetc()`

Comment: Note: C spec has "it is permitted to take the address of a library function even if it is also defined as a macro." §7.1.4 1 - not that that spec applies much here, but does discuss the "address of a library function"  Note, Footnote says "This means that an implementation shall provide an actual function for each library function, even if it
also provides a macro for that function." - hmmm.

Comment: There's also 6.9.5: "If an identiﬁer declared with external linkage is used in an expression ... somewhere in the entire program there shall be exactly one external deﬁnition for the identiﬁer", and 7.1.2.6: "Any declaration of a library function shall have external linkage". If `getc` is aliased to `fgetc`, then I guess it's debatable whether there is an "external definition for the [former] *identifier*."

Comment: I suspect the "guarantee that pointers to differently-named standard functions must compare not-equal" is false.  My review of the spec does not find a such a retirement, but I think it will take more than that to well answer your **good** question.  Good luck.

Comment: I would expect to find any explicit provision to such effect in [section 7.1](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.1) of the standard, the introduction to the standard library.  It contains no such provision.

Comment: While not the standard, the *man pages* help muddy the water, e.g. `man 3 getc` *"getc() is equivalent to fgetc() except that it may be implemented as a macro which evaluates stream  more than once."*

Comment: Whatever the standard may or may not say about it, [experimentation](https://ideone.com/bwy0tD) shows that in at least some implementations, `&fgetc == &getc` evaluates true.

Comment: As it turns out, @DavidC.Rankin, that man page excerpt is also [an excerpt from the standard](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.7.5p2).  But even so, I don't think it clearly contradicts the existence of a requirement of the kind that R.. posits.  (Notwithstanding that I think there indeed is no such requirement.)

Comment: Agreed. Funny, I tested gcc and got `not same: 0x4004b0  0x4004d0` on the `fgetc/getc` check. The crux of the contradiction is what was raised by @chux with "*an implementation shall provide an actual function for each library function*" which is hard to square with the "*Two pointers compare equal if and only if both are null pointers, both are pointers to the same... function*" raised in the question (and the results you obtained). Gotta love legal loopholes to the Standard via implementation details.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I do not see a contradiction.  When `fgetc == getc`, there are the same function.  When they differ, they are no the same function - even if functionally identical.  AFAIK, a compliant library can do either.  Lacking a spec, I expect C to allow what is most flexible and least constraining on an implementation.

Comment: @chux, my only quandary was the footnote you cited. If the standard requires each implementation to provide an actual *function* for each *library function*, then I take that to mean an actual function declaration and definition. If interpreted that way, there is no way I can see that `fgetc == getc` could ever occur. Now the devil is in the detail and if *"shall provide an actual function for each library function"* doesn't really mean an *actual function* with its own declaration and definition, then I guess that's just C-legal-ease (e.g. *weasel-words*)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Yet the spec did not say "a unique function" for each library function.  To muddy the waters: Recall that functions like `fgetc, getc` need not be implemented in C. `fgetc, getc` could even have different binary values, yet equate to each other - somewhat like -0.0 == +0.0.  Without C implementation limitations, 2 function signatures need not be the same and the 2 functions may "exist" at the same address.  Hmmm, all this discourse adds evidence that "Guarantee of non-equality of pointers to standard functions" does not exist.  Hard to prove non-existence though.

Comment: What the question and follow-on comments keenly expose is "guarantee isn't always as guaranteed or unambiguous as one would think" from a standard standpoint. Yes, I agree with the widest possible implementation view. While whether `getc/fgetc`, etc.. are, or are not, capable of pointer equivalence makes little difference to a majority, it seems like something you should be able to simply deduce from from the standard. While I can't foresee a need to compare such function pointers for equivalence, I'm sure somebody else will. The crux seems to be, "don't rely on it." Good discussion.

Answer (score 0):

No, I don't believe there is any such guarantee.

I believe this whole discussion originates from the part of the standard which allows a function to also be defined as a macro with the same name.

From C17 7.1.4:

> Any
>   function declared in a header may be additionally implemented as a function-like macro defined
>   in the header, so if a library function is declared explicitly when its header is included, one of the
>   techniques shown below can be used to ensure the declaration is not affected by such a macro. Any
>   macro definition of a function can be suppressed locally by enclosing the name of the function in
>   parentheses, because the name is then not followed by the left parenthesis that indicates expansion of
>   a macro function name. For the same syntactic reason, it is permitted to take the address of a library
>   function even if it is also defined as a macro<sup>189)</sup>.
>
> ---
>
> <sup>189)</sup> This means that an implementation shall provide an actual function for each library function, even if it also provides a
>   macro for that function.

The text goes on describing how users may `#undef` the macro name if they want to be guaranteed that they get an actual function.

So it is allowed for the implementation to have a standard function and a macro with the same name. But what the macro then expands to is implementation-defined. It may very well be an internal function with the same address as what another library macro expands to.

Based on that, I don't believe there are any guarantees that different functions have different addresses.

In the specific case of `getc`, the standard says (C17 7.21.7.5):

> The getc function is equivalent to fgetc, except that if it is implemented as a macro, it may evaluate `stream` more than once, so the argument should never be an expression
>   with side effects.

I would say it is somewhat likely that the implementation calls the same actual function for `fgetc` and `getc` when these are implemented as macros. (Or that `atoi` versus `strtol` call the same function, etc etc). The standard library implementations I have peeked at don't seem to do it this way, but I don't think there is anything in the standard stopping them.

---

(As a side note, taking the address of library functions may not be a good idea for other reasons, namely that it may block inlining of that function within the same translation unit.)

Answer (score 0):

Well you are falling in an *implementation detail*. The standard only specifies the *behaviour* of the functions of the standard library.

For `getc` the spec says (emphasize mine):

> The getc function is equivalent to fgetc, except that if it is implemented as a macro, it
>   **may** evaluate stream more than once, so the argument **should** never be an expression
>   with side effects.

So the implementation may implement `getc` as a macro, but it also may implement it as an alias (a mere pointer to func) to `fgetc` or as a different function with same behaviour. Long story short you cannot rely on `&getc == &fgetc` to be true or false.

---

The only thing that the standard requires is that '&getc` must be defined per 7.1.4 § 1:

> ... it is permitted to take the address of a library function even if it is also defined as
>   a macro...

That just means that the implementation must have a function of that name, but it could:

- be the `fgets` function - ok `&fgetc == &getc` is true
- use the macro - `fgetc == &getc` is false
- call the `fgets` function - `&fgetc == &getc` is false